# Does the following series converge or diverge $\sum_{i=0}^{n}{(\frac{n}{1+n})^n}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I would like to know whether the following series diverges or converges:
$$\sum_{i=0}^{n}{(\frac{n}{1+n})^n}$$

I tried running some of the convergence tests that I found online, but none of them seemed to work. I was hoping that the $n^{th}$ term divergence test might give me the fact that the series diverges, but sadly I did not get that.

Anyhow, any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think you've put $n$ instead of $i$?

Comment: Hint: $(1+1/n)^{-n} \to e^{-1} \neq 0$

Comment: Also, you put an $n$ instead of $\infty$?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your question is about the convergence or divergence of the following series
$$ a_n = \sum_{m=0}^{n}{\left(\frac{m}{m+1}\right)}^m, $$
the answer is that the series diverges.

The series is equivalent to
$$ a_n = \sum_{m=1}^{n+1}{\left(\frac{m-1}{m}\right)}^{m-1}=\sum_{m=1}^{n+1}{\left(1-\frac{1}{m}\right)}^{m-1}.$$

Intuitively, we can see
$$\lim_{m \rightarrow \infty}{\left(1-\frac{1}{m}\right)}^{m-1} = \lim_{m \rightarrow \infty}{\left(1-\frac{1}{m}\right)}^m = e^{-1}. $$
As $n \rightarrow \infty,$ those many items in the summation with large $m$ values are all close to $e^{-1}$ (a constant). Hence the summation goes to $\infty$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$.

To actually prove the divergence, we can use the following reasoning.

Since $\lim_{m \rightarrow \infty}{\left(1-\frac{1}{m}\right)}^{m-1} = e^{-1}$, for any $\epsilon > 0, \epsilon < e^{-1}$, we can find a sufficiently large $N$ so that for all $m\ge N$, we have $\left(1-\frac{1}{m}\right)^{m-1}>e^{-1} - \epsilon$.

And for $n > N$, $$ a_n > \sum_{m=N+1}^{n+1}{\left(1-\frac{1}{m}\right)}^{m-1} > \sum_{m=N+1}^{n+1}\left(e^{-1} - \epsilon\right) = \left(e^{-1} - \epsilon\right)(n-N+1), $$ and the series diverges as $n\rightarrow \infty$.

Answer (score 0):

You can verify the divergence of the series quite quickly using the [Bernoulli inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality) bounding the series from below by the divergent harmonic series $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k}$:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{(\frac{n}{1+n})^n} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{(1-\frac{1}{1+n})^n}\stackrel{Bernoulli}{\geq} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{(1-\frac{n}{1+n})}= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{1+n}}=\infty$$

Answer (score 0):

Starting after Xiaohai Zhang's answer, considering
$$a_n = \sum_{m=0}^{n}b_m\qquad \text{with}\qquad b_m={\left(\frac{m}{m+1}\right)}^m$$ consider, for large values of $m$
$$\log(b_m)=m \log\left(\frac{m}{m+1}\right)=-m \log\left(1+\frac1{m}\right)$$ and use Taylor to get
$$\log(b_m)=m \left(-\frac{1}{m}+\frac{1}{2 m^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{m^3}\right) \right)=-1+\frac{1}{2 m}+O\left(\frac{1}{m^2}\right) $$ COntinue with Taylor using
$$b_m=e^{\log(b_m)}=\frac 1e+\frac{1}{2e m}+O\left(\frac{1}{m^2}\right) $$ that is to say that $b_m >\frac 1e$ and this is true $\forall m$. Then divergence.

If you generate a table of the $a_n$'s and plot them, you will notice that they are almost along a straight line with a slope just a bit larger than $\frac 1e$. For example $a_{1000}\approx 369.161$ while $\frac {1000}e \approx 367.879$.